# How to execute a shell script on EC-2 instance using java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I need to write a java program to create an AWS EC2 instance in Mumbai region.
The program should also be able to execute a shell script on EC2 instance after the instance is in ready state. I don't want to hard code script in my program. The program should read a external script file. I am unable to find a document which gives a idea about how to do it.

This is what I came up with:

```
public class CreateInstance
{
    private static final AWSCredentials AWS_CREDENTIALS;

    static {
        // Your accesskey and secretkey
        AWS_CREDENTIALS = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                "My ID",
                "My secret"
        );
    }

    public static Integer getInstanceStatus(String instanceId, AmazonEC2 ec2) {
        DescribeInstancesRequest describeInstanceRequest = new DescribeInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds(instanceId);
        DescribeInstancesResult describeInstanceResult = ec2.describeInstances(describeInstanceRequest);
        InstanceState state = describeInstanceResult.getReservations().get(0).getInstances().get(0).getState();
        return state.getCode();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set up the amazon ec2 client
        AmazonEC2 ec2Client = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(AWS_CREDENTIALS))
                .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1)
                .build();

        // Launch an Amazon EC2 Instance
        RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest().withImageId("ami-009110a2bf8d7dd0a")
                .withInstanceType("t2.micro") // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html
                .withMinCount(1)
                .withMaxCount(1)
                .withKeyName("prakhar")
                .withNetworkInterfaces(new InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification()
                        .withAssociatePublicIpAddress(true)
                        .withDeviceIndex(0));

        RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = ec2Client.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);

        Instance instance = runInstancesResult.getReservation().getInstances().get(0);
        String instanceId = instance.getInstanceId(); 
        //String Id = instanceId;
        System.out.println("EC2 Instance Id: " + instanceId);

        // Setting up the tags for the instance
        CreateTagsRequest createTagsRequest = new CreateTagsRequest()
                .withResources(instance.getInstanceId())
                .withTags(new Tag("Name", "prakhardemo"));
        ec2Client.createTags(createTagsRequest);

        // Starting the Instance
        StartInstancesRequest startInstancesRequest = new StartInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds(instanceId);

        ec2Client.startInstances(startInstancesRequest);
        //wait until its in running state
        Integer instanceState = -1;
        while(instanceState != 16) { //Loop until the instance is in the "running" state.
            instanceState = getInstanceStatus(instanceId, ec2Client);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        System.out.println("your created instance is now in running state !");
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) Might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [AWS EC2 User Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

> When you launch an instance in Amazon EC2, you have the option of passing user data to the instance that can be used to perform common automated configuration tasks and even run scripts after the instance starts.

Change your code as follows:

```
RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest().withImageId("ami-009110a2bf8d7dd0a")
    .withInstanceType("t2.micro") // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html
    .withMinCount(1)
    .withMaxCount(1)
    .withKeyName("prakhar")
    .withUserData(getUserDataScript())
    .withNetworkInterfaces(new InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification()
        .withAssociatePublicIpAddress(true)
        .withDeviceIndex(0));
```

Where `getUserDataScript()` can be as follows:

```
private static String getUserDataScript(){
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    # Open and Read Your File into Lines

    String str = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(join(lines, "\n").getBytes()));
    return str;
}
```